# Add to path from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a shell script in Linux Mint, that adds a directory to my path.

the contents of the script successfully adds to my path when I just paste it into the terminal.

But when I invoke the script from within the terminal, nothing happens.

The script I am running, is as follow...

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android_sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: @MikhailKrutov 's answer is correct. His last sentence really means that in order to modify your current shell's environment, you need to execute your script in it, by `source`-ing it.  Also see answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/53177/bash-script-to-set-environment-variables-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because when you invoke it, you create a sub shell, which has its own context and its own environment.

When script shell exits, it doesnt' affect the parent shell.

Any environmental variable changes should go through `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, etc.

if you want it to be a separate script, you should use `source /path/to/script` instead of executing it.